# The hangman game backward #7

Tags: riddle, knowledge, english, language, letters

Hangman game backward #7 - guess what was the question:

fill in a "d" - If this is marked on the calendar, you might be in some trouble.
fill in a "h" - Google picture of this, you'll find mostly music sheets and a kind of sport.
fill in a "l" - Open me and you'll usually find your beloved one.
fill in a "p" - It is believed that in some Asia country, this is where some monsters live.
fill in a "r" - "Fly me to the moon, and let me play among the stars"
fill in a "s" - You might feel your lack of power disturbing without me.

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

First answer that fully explained each line will be accepted, enjoy!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> _ o c k e t

fill in a "d" - If this is marked on the calendar, you might be in some trouble.

> Dockets are related to (law) cases

fill in a "h" - Google picture of this, you'll find mostly music sheets and a kind of sport.

> Hocket is a musical term

fill in a "l" - Open me and you'll usually find your beloved one.

> Locket holds a picture

fill in a "p" - It is believed that in some Asia country, this is where some monsters live.

> Pocket monster! I choose you!

fill in a "r" - "Fly me to the moon, and let me play among the stars"

> Rocket

fill in a "s" - You might feel your lack of power disturbing without me.

> Socket, where you plug stuff in

Comment: Beat me to it! Good work!

Comment: Nice and fast, good work!  I hope it's not too easy for you

Comment: @Alex I was kinda stumped until I got to R.  That got me on track, and the rest fell into place.

Comment: How is h***** a sport? Isn't the last letter wrong?

Comment: @Arc676 yes, it must be a common typo.

Comment: @Arc676 yes, as Jasen stated, a common typo.  That's why when you google picture of it and you see hocke'y' as well

Answer (score 4):

The arrangement of letters was:

> _ocket.

Comment: Spoiler tags are like block quotes, just use >! instead of >